# Google Analytics Android SDK event labels don't support end parenthesis?

Tags: android, google-analytics, parentheses

I'm trying to implement Google Analytics in my app, and I want to register some events. The label is dynamic, and some of the content has parentheses in their titles. When I check the `Event Tracking`, it shows up like this:

```
"Event Label (Something something"
```

When it's supposed to be:

```
"Event label (Something something) something else"
```

I tried url-encoding it, but of course that makes it show up as:

```
"Event+label+%28Something+something%29+something+else"
```

Is it possible to get parentheses to show correctly?

Comment: No. That would require the same amount of work as just removing them, and I was looking for a better route. I did put some unique numbers in front of it, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Just found this too. I couldn't find any mention of it in the documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#trackingModes

Comment: Hi @AmITheRWord; i have the same problem as yours. Have you been able to find a solution? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486332/using-easytracker-trackevent-with-strings-containing-character)

Comment: @syloc No, I'm sorry. I found a compromise, where I put the unique ID of the thing causing the event in front of it, so I would be able to differentiate two similar events.